# convert object to express dynamic routes

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have an object that looks like:

```
{
    api: {
        test: function () {}
    },
    routes: {
        docs: {
            options: function () {},
            usage: function () {}
        },
        index: function () {},
        bugs: {
            report: function () {}
        }
    }
}
```

Which is a object that mapped my application controllers by walking the directory tree and requiring each file inside the dir if there was a file. The file returns a `module.exports` function.

What I'm trying to do, is have the following routing in express:

```
application.get("/", controllers.routes.index);
application.get("/partials/index", controllers.routes.partials.index);
application.get("/partials/documentation/amd", controllers.routes.partials.documentation.amd);
application.get("/partials/documentation/api", controllers.routes.partials.documentation.api);
application.get("/partials/documentation/jquery", controllers.routes.partials.documentation.jquery);
application.get("/partials/documentation/options", controllers.routes.partials.documentation.options);
application.get("/partials/documentation/usage", controllers.routes.partials.documentation.usage);
application.get("/partials/installation/bower", controllers.routes.partials.installation.bower);
application.get("/partials/installation/source", controllers.routes.partials.installation.source);
application.get("/partials/compatibility/methods", controllers.routes.partials.compatibility.methods);
application.get("/partials/compatibility/support", controllers.routes.partials.compatibility.support);
application.get("/partials/bugs/requests", controllers.routes.partials.bugs.requests);
application.get("/partials/bugs/report", controllers.routes.partials.bugs.report);
application.get("*", controllers.routes.index);
```

somehow dynamic instead of hardcoding each one. I cannot figure out a logic to do so, I was thinking of doing something like:

```
var keys = Object.keys(controllers), //where controllers is my object containing the routes and api, what I just wrote one block of code above
    length = keys.length - 1;

while (length >= 0) {
    ... something that will check the object if it will contain any other object and will do a recursive iteration, then will somehow concatenate the parent object keys ...
}
```

I'm not sure how I could get all the parent keys of the subobject (something like `routes docs options`), because that is what I actually need to compose the route string that is passed to express.

Comment: this one is somehow reverse ? maybe, not sure. But this thing will read the object and compose the route string instead ... it does look very much like what you showed me before

Comment: Yes they do, just that I didn't add all of it :) The `routes` key actually contains the `partials` object, so it will match to `/partials/compatibility/methods` (`routes: { partials: { compatibility: { methods: function() {} ... } } }`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (http://jsfiddle.net/trevordixon/hym76/):

```
function registerRoutes(path, routes, level) {
    var level = level || 0;

    for (var p in routes) {
        if (typeof routes[p] === 'function') {
            if (p === 'index' && level === 0) app.get(path, routes[p]);
            else app.get(path + p, routes[p]);
        } else {
            // Recursive call; adds ancestors to the path with each call
            registerRoutes(path + p + '/', routes[p], level+1);
        }
    }
}

registerRoutes('/', controllers.routes);
registerRoutes('/api/', controllers.api);
```

Comment: that seems about right ... I'll try it out to see if it works on my end :)

Comment: there is also an `app.get('/partials/index', ...)`, that one seems to be omitted or removed, perhaps because `if (p === 'index') app.get(path, routes[p]);` ?

Comment: So maybe instead of rendering `app.get('/partials/index', ...)` it does `app.get('/', ...)`

Comment: It would do `app.get('/partials/', ...)`, and yes, it's because of that condition check `if (p === 'index') ...`. You could do something like http://jsfiddle.net/trevordixon/hym76/. Get rid of that condition, and instead of `'index'` for the `/` route, use `''` (empty string).

Comment: That was the only solution I came up with too, but is there a way to check if I'm on the first level when doing the loop ? Because the index on the first level will always default to `app.get('/', ...)`. I'm thinking of doing a loop before and counting the levels and then on the second loop (the function you posted) check the level I'm on, or something like that ...

Comment: Add another function parameter to track the level. I'll update the answer.